# SQL View to flatten out a hierarchy

Tags: sql

I have a table with some parent child relationships. I want to create a view  that has all possible ids for a location id.

I need the sql to do this

```
Table:

ID  PARENT_ID   LOCATION_ID
1   NULL        ABC
2   1           XYZ
3   NULL        EFG

view results:

LOCATION_ID     ID
XYZ             1
XYZ             2
ABC             1
ABC             2
EFG             3
```

Comment: What's the database engine? Sybase, Oracle, PostgreSQL, etc.

Comment: Why is 3 the only id for EFG? Why is it not an option for ABC and XYZ?

Comment: database engine would be Snowflake, but I assume similar to Oracle.

Comment: Some ids would not have a parent id.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention the database you are using, so I'll assume PostgreSQL. You can adjust the answer to your specific engine:

```
with recursive
n as (
  select id, id as grp, location_id from t where parent_id is null
  union all
  select t.id, n.grp, t.location_id
  from n
  join t on t.parent_id = n.id
)
select b.id, a.location_id
from n a
join n b on a.grp = b.grp
```

Result:

```
id location_id
-- -----------
1  ABC
2  ABC
1  XYZ
2  XYZ
3  EFG
```

For the record, the data script I used is:

```
create table t (
  id int,
  parent_id int,
  location_id varchar(10)
);

insert into t (id, parent_id, location_id) values 
  (1, null, 'ABC'),
  (2, 1,    'XYZ'),
  (3, null, 'EFG');
```